# How do I redo a for...of loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, redo, for-of-loop

In Ruby, the `redo` keyword can be used to go back to the beginning of a loop without consuming input. I'd like to do the same with a `for...of` loop in JavaScript.

```js
const scan = lexer => function* (string) {
  let [token, table] = lexer;

  for (const character of string) {
    const next = table.get(character);

    if (next) {
      [token, table] = next.value;
    } else if (token) {
      yield token.value;
      [token, table] = lexer;
      // redo the current iteration without consuming input
    } else {
      throw new SyntaxError("Unexpected character", character);
    }
  }

  if (token) yield token.value;
  else throw new SyntaxError("Unexpected end of input");
}
```

Normally, you'd do this by simply not incrementing the index of a regular `for` loop. However, I have to use a `for...of` loop because it loops over the Unicode code points of the string, whereas the regular `for` loop would loop over the UTF-16 code units of the string.

How do I go back to the beginning of the loop without duplication of code?

Comment: Don't think you can...

Comment: Labels? ... ...

Comment: You can first call `Array.from()` on your string, which will give you a plain array of the codepoints in the string. You can then use an ordinary `for` loop with an index value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an inner loop:

```
 for (const character of string) {
   while(true) {
     const next = table.get(character);       
     if (next) {
       [token, table] = next.value;
       break;
     } else if (token) {
       yield token.value;
       [token, table] = lexer;      
       // don't break, redo
     } else {
       throw new SyntaxError("Unexpected character", character);
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

---

To restart the *whole loop*:

In your case it's actually quite straightforward:

```
 yield* scan(lexer)(string);
 return;
```

For sure if you don't want to restart the whole function, add an IIFE and recall that:

```
 yield* (function redo*() {
   //...
  yield* redo();
  return;
})();
```

If you really need jumps, use labels (please don't):

```
 restart: while(true) {
  // do stuff
  continue restart;
  //...
  break;
}
```

Comment: No, that would be an infinite loop because it would start at the beginning again.

Comment: Isn't that what you are asking? Or do you just want to redo the current iteration? In that case, use an inner loop.

Comment: Redo the current iteration. Edited my question to clarify that.